# Grep reliably all C #defines

Tags: python, c, regex, macros

I need to analyse some C files and print out all the #define found.
It's not that hard with a regexp (for example)

```
def with_regexp(fname):
    print("{0}:".format(fname))
    for line in open(fname):
        match = macro_regexp.match(line)
        if match is not None:
            print(match.groups())
```

But for example it doesn't handle multiline defines for example.

There is a nice way to do it in C for example with

```
gcc -E -dM file.c
```

the problem is that it returns all the #defines, not just the one from the given file, and I don't find any option to only use the given file..

Any hint?
Thanks

EDIT:
This is a first solution to filter out the unwanted defines, simply checking that the name of the define is actually part of the original file, not perfect but seems to work nicely..

```
def with_gcc(fname):
    cmd = "gcc -dM -E {0}".format(fname)
    proc = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    out, err = proc.communicate()
    source = open(fname).read()
    res = set()

    for define in out.splitlines():
        name = define.split(' ')[1]
        if re.search(name, source):
            res.add(define)

    return res
```

Comment: Your question says grep, but your code is in Python. Which is it to be?

Comment: Grep is an English word, not just the name of a command..

Comment: are you [sure](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Grep) about that ?

Comment: Anyway, I think anyone understood the `grep` in the question. Moreover even if it is not an English word, it is definitely a Programming word.

Comment: @c00kiemon5ter: The [OED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grep?q=grep) has it, but the definition is a bit spotty. The [Jargon file](http://www.retrologic.com/jargon/G/grep.html) fares a bit better.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for a shell one-liner!

What I want to do is remove the all `#include`s from the C file (so we don't get junk from other files), pass that off to `gcc -E -dM`, then remove all the built in `#define`s - those start with `_`, and apparently `linux` and `unix`.

If you have `#define`s that start with an underscore this won't work exactly as promised.

It goes like this:

```
sed -e '/#include/d' foo.c | gcc -E -dM - | sed -e '/#define \(linux\|unix\|_\)/d'
```

You could probably do it in a few lines of Python too.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell you could do something like the following:

```
function Get-Defines {
  param([string] $Path)

  "$Path`:"
  switch -regex -file $Path {
    '\\$' {
      if ($multiline) { $_ }
    }
    '^\s*#define(.*)$' {
      $multiline = $_.EndsWith('\');
      $_
    }
    default {
      if ($multiline) { $_ }
      $multiline = $false
    }
  }
}
```

Using the following sample file

```
#define foo "bar"
blah
#define FOO \
  do { \
    do_stuff_here \
    do_more_stuff \
  } while (0)
blah
blah
    #define X
```

it prints

```
\x.c:
#define foo "bar"
#define FOO \
  do { \
    do_stuff_here \
    do_more_stuff \
  } while (0)
        #define X
```

Not ideal, at least how idiomatic PowerShell functions should work, but should work well enough for your needs.

Comment: Luckily I'm not going to use powershell, and does this handle multiline defines anyway?

Comment: Why luckily? And yes, it does.

Comment: Because it's horrible..Anyway I trust much more using GCC, at least I'm sure that it always work and I'm not forgetting some special cases, so I will probably avoid using regular expression, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in pure python I'd use a small state machine:

```
def getdefines(fname):
    """ return a list of all define statements in the file """
    lines = open(fname).read().split("\n") #read in the file as a list of lines
    result = [] #the result list
    current = []#a temp list that holds all lines belonging to a define
    lineContinuation = False #was the last line break escaped with a '\'?

    for line in lines:
        #is the current line the start or continuation of a define statement?
        isdefine = line.startswith("#define") or lineContinuation
        if isdefine:
            current.append(line) #append to current result
            lineContinuation = line.endswith("\\") #is the line break escaped?
            if not lineContinuation:
                #we reached the define statements end - append it to result list
                result.append('\n'.join(current))
                current = [] #empty the temp list

    return result
```